# Filter on a Query Item

Tags: report, cognos

I am creating a report and have a field that has multiple values representing different data values. i.e 4-Completeness 5-accuracy etc... What I need to do is make multiple columns where that field is filtered down to one value. The problem is I get the error if I try and edit the query item in the report of 'Boolen value expression as query item is not supported' How do I fix?

example:

```
    ID column | Data Value = 4 | Actual Data | Data Value = 5
```

EDIT:
I currently have a case when [Data value] = 4 then [percentage] for the different columns but I am still getting wrong output. I am getting

```
    ID1  | 45% |       |      |
    ID1  |     |  35%  |      |
    ID1  |     |       |  67% |
```

I need all of ID1 to be in one row.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this by totaling by ID which will combine all three rows in your example to one:

```
total([Measure] for [ID])
```

Change each of the three percentage columns to use this expression, substituting their respective data item for [Measure].

Normally, you don't want to total percentages, but this is an exception. Since only one row has actual data, the total will match that row and the other two null values will not be included in the total.

Comment: When I do this I am getting the error 'invalid token "for" found after total([Measure])'

Comment: That's odd. This is very basic aggregate syntax. Are you using the expression above in a custom data item or filter? It won't work as a filter.

Comment: I am using in as a query calculation

Comment: If you posted the exact error message, then your syntax is incorrect.  The `for [ID]` goes **inside** the parens.

Comment: So I just got access to the framework today and looked into the query items I am trying to use and what I am using for my [Measure] is defined as a character and not a number. Also cannot be cast as a number because whoever filled the tables added decimals in some places and not others and also there are '%' signs in the data. I believe this is my problem of why this will not work

Comment: That would explain the problem. I assumed the percentages in your example were formatting of numerical data. Cognos will never combine attributes (non-measures). You'll have to massage the data with substring() and other functions to remove non-numeric data in order to get rid of the extra rows.

Comment: @TonyQuiriconi, if your goal is to get 1 row per ID with 3 columns for your "measures", try grouping on ID using max on your measure columns.

Answer (score -1):

Simple way would be to do it for each data value in three queries and join them on ID1